# Angular ng-repeat-start inside a different "level" tag that ng-repeat-end. Is it a bug?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I ran into this situation where I needed to repeat an HTML code block with `ng-repeat-start` / `ng-repeat-end` but had angular complaining that:

> Error: [$compile:uterdir] Unterminated attribute, found 'ng-repeat-start' but no matching 'ng-repeat-end' found.

I found a workaround which it might be useful to someone that will run into this situation. I would also like to know what you think. Is it a bug? I should have avoided that approach? I am using Angular v1.3.5 and the code is like that:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    ...
    <tr ng-repeat-start="a in b">
      ...
    </tr>
    ...
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    ...
  </tbody>
  <thead>
    ...
    <tr ng-repeat-end>
      ...
    </tr>
    ...
  </thead>
</table>
```

The problem seems to be that the `ng-repeat-end` is not within the same HTML tag block (here the first `thead` that `ng-repeat-start` is inside).

I found a workaround with the following code:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    ...
  </thead>
  <thead ng-repeat-start="a in b">
    <tr>
      ...
    </tr>
    ...
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    ...
  </tbody>
  <thead>
    ...
  </thead>
  <thead ng-repeat-end>
    <tr>
      ...
    </tr>
    ...
  </thead>
</table>
```

This way I am bringing the `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` within the same tag, the `table`.

Comment: exact, ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end must be siblings

Comment: here are the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-multielement- . There is nothing explicitly saying nodes must be siblings, but that could be implied by `compiler will collect DOM nodes between nodes with the attributes directive-name-start and directive-name-end`

Answer (score 1):

ngRepeat is a [multiElement](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-multielement-) directive.

If you look through the [$compile source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js), you can see that angularJs will loop through next *sibling* nodes:

```
/**
 * Given a node with an directive-start it collects all of the siblings until it finds
 * directive-end.
 * @param node
 * @param attrStart
 * @param attrEnd
 * @returns {*}
 */
function groupScan(node, attrStart, attrEnd) {
  var nodes = [];
  var depth = 0;
  if (attrStart && node.hasAttribute && node.hasAttribute(attrStart)) {
    do {
      if (!node) {
        throw $compileMinErr('uterdir',
                  "Unterminated attribute, found '{0}' but no matching '{1}' found.",
                  attrStart, attrEnd);
      }
      if (node.nodeType == NODE_TYPE_ELEMENT) {
        if (node.hasAttribute(attrStart)) depth++;
        if (node.hasAttribute(attrEnd)) depth--;
      }
      nodes.push(node);
      node = node.nextSibling;
    } while (depth > 0);
  } else {
    nodes.push(node);
  }

  return jqLite(nodes);
}
```

On a personnal account, trying to use this with non-siblings elements feels very unnatural to the treeish nature of HTML.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. That was the idea behind the workaround that I suggested. However the case that I run into had a repeating pattern that was not satistfying the sibling condition and which is an accepted approach (I think).